# Closure and Callbacks

Tags: java, closures

Is there any other way in java to implement call backs apart from inner classes? What is the difference between callbacks and closures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Closure is how you build it, callback is how you use it.

A callback can be implemented as a closure (in languages that have them) or an implementation of an interface (in Java, as an anonymous inner class or a regular class).

Callback means that you pass a piece of code to a function, so that the function can call that piece of code later. It is a special kind of parameter.

The piece of code can be a function pointer or a closure or an object with well-known methods, depending on what the language offers.

Comment: This was the answer I was trying to write when Neeraj first dropped the question but couldn't get out in a coherent fashion.  Kudos.

Answer (score 5):

Both closures and anonymous inner classes (and others) can be used as callbacks. A [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_science)) is just some code which is passed as an argument to other code.

A big difference of closures, compared to Java's anonymous inner classes, is that (in imperative languages) a closure can modify the variables of the surrounding scope. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)#Differences_in_semantics) gives the following example:

```
var f, g;
function foo() {
  var x = 0;
  f = function() { return ++x; };
  g = function() { return --x; };
  x = 1;
  alert('inside foo, call to f(): ' + f()); // "2"
}
foo();
alert('call to g(): ' + g()); // "1"
alert('call to f(): ' + f()); // "2"
```

Comment: Although this can be emulated by `final ObjRef<Integer> x=new ObjRef<Integer>(0);` with `ObjRef` implemented as mutable reference.

Comment: Actually Scala does something like that to implement closures on the JVM, because JVM (and Java) does not support them natively.

Answer (score 1):

A callback is just any executable code that is passed as a parameter to other code.  In frequent usage, that executable code is a closure, but it's not necessarily.

The word closure is somewhat abused and many people just use it as a synonym for "anonymous function", but at least [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), that's a misuse of the term.  The Wikipedia article explains this better than I can do quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need closures in java you could try [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/). [Here](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/Closures) you can see how it allows to define closures through a very straightforward DSL.

Comment: Actually, lambdaj does not support the creation of closures.  At best it supports the creation of some kinds of lambda expressions that are not closures.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

If there is, then it is probably inferior in some way, otherwise anonymous inner classes wouldn't be widely used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

Closures can be defined as a block of code holding parent context that can be executed with ease.

In fact, the only difference I know between those is the ease of writing. A typical groovy/ruby closure is indeed smaller to write than a Java anonymous class.

However, considering Java framworks like [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and there liberal use of anonymous classes/interfaces, particularly for typical closures use cases like [filter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) (comparing with groovy's [implementation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure))), I can say there is absolutely no design difference.

Comment: If there is no difference then why these two names exist. I am clueless

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the only reasonable way is inner/anonymous classes.

You can also do it with reflection, but that usually is slower and harder in maintenance (no syntax highlighting, hard to find references in IDE etc.). An example:

```
myButton.addActionListener(EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, handlerObject, "onClick"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For now anonymous classes are the best way of handling callbacks in Java.  However this is likely to change come Java 7 which will implement closures. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is two implementations that uses closures and callbacks.

- http://www.caglargonul.com/2013/04/05/playing-with-closures-in-java-7/
- http://www.caglargonul.com/2013/04/05/java7-callback-implementation/

And here is a better example (can be found here http://www.caglargonul.com/2013/04/10/is-it-really-a-closure-yes-it-is/ ) for understanding what closure is. The key is that

> a closure comes with a referencing environment not just a function code.

The best way to implement a closure in Java 7 and below is using an interface. In this example a callback is implemented as closure.

You first declare your interface which will hold your closure.

```
public interface CallBack {
    void m(int e);
}
```

And lets add a class responsible for holding an array of closures, two public methods for adding and removing closures and a public function which will call the functions inside the closures when an event occurs.

```
public class CCallBack {

    List<CallBack> cbs = new ArrayList<>();

    public void registerCallBack(CallBack f){
        cbs.add(f);
    }

    public void removeCallBack(CallBack f){
        if(cbs.contains(f)){
            cbs.remove(f);
        }
    }

    public void onAction(int i){
        for (CallBack callBack : cbs) {
            callBack.m(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the magical part. See the referencing environment in action.

```
public class CallBackTester {
    CCallBack cb = new CCallBack();

    @Test
    public void test_callback(){

        CallBack cb1 = new CallBack() {
            int x = 1;
            @Override
            public void m(int e) {
                if(e==1){
                    System.out.println("You register this callback " + x + " time/times");
                    x++;
                }
            }
        };

        cb.registerCallBack(cb1);
        cb.registerCallBack(cb1);
        cb.registerCallBack(cb1);
        cb.removeCallBack(cb1);

        cb.onAction(1);
    }

}
```

Above when we declare cb1 we are adding a referencing environment which consists of the variable x. When we call the function inside this closure we are incrementing this variable by one. If it was a normal function, x would have been declared as 1 when we call the function. BUT IT IS NOT A NORMAL FUNCTION. IT IS A CLOSURE. So x is not declared every time we call the function in the closure. As you can see from the output every time we call it, x is incrementing.

```
You register this callback 1 time/times
You register this callback 2 time/times
```